# Does running Valgrind slow down my application?

Tags: linux, memory, valgrind

I simply want to keep track of how much memory various processes are using (different options can radically change the memory usage of this particular application). I don't like the various "find the process pid and grok /proc/pid/smaps" solutions described elsewhere...

Is there an alternative command to use that will just dump memory usage of a particular process? memusage?

Answer (score 6):

According to [Valgrind Manual](http://valgrind.org/docs/manual/manual-core.html), Valgrind will very noticeably slow down your application:

> The amount of instrumentation code added varies widely between tools.
>   At one end of the scale, Memcheck adds code to check every memory
>   access and every value computed, making it run 10-50 times slower than
>   natively. At the other end of the spectrum, the minimal tool, called
>   Nulgrind, adds no instrumentation at all and causes in total "only"
>   about a 4 times slowdown.

In my experience Valgrind indeed slows down an application by about factor 10.

How detailed do you need the memory usage to be reported? Is `top` (`RES` column) not sufficient?

Comment: top (RES column) is fine, I just want an automatic way to do it.

Comment: Then maybe try something like this: `awk '{print 4*$2}' < /proc/30321/statm` which will print the RES memory usage (in kilobytes) for PID 30321. See "man proc" (http://linux.die.net/man/5/proc) for details on the meaning of the /proc/<pid>/statm file.

Comment: Is there a bash way to find the pid in one line? i.e. "run_x; awk '{print 4*$2}' < /proc/${xxy}/statm"?

Comment: Yes, `${!}` is a special shell variable that contains the PID of the last process started in background. So `run_x & awk '{print 4*$2}' < /proc/${!}/statm` will start "run_x" and then print the RES memory - but note that this will only print the memory usage once, right at start. You could probably add a loop to the command to periodically print the memory usage instead. Have a look at shell scripting tutorials for the details.

Comment: @oliver, if Nulgrind is used, the ability of finding `memory leaks` error is same as Valgrind? Is there any degradation?

Comment: @ChuongLe, unfortunately Nulgrind is not useful as memory checking tool. According to the user manual (https://valgrind.org/docs/manual/nl-manual.html): "[Nulgrind] performs no instrumentation or analysis of a program, just runs it normally. It is mainly of use for Valgrind's developers for debugging and regression testing.". So you will not find memory leaks with Nulgrind; you have to use Memcheck for that.

Comment: @oliver, I got it. It is obviously that if Nulgrind can replace Valgrind/memcheck. Then nobody will use Valgrind/memcheck which is at least 10 times slower. Thanks for your pointing out!

Answer (score 1):

Just had a look with "time valgrind memhog 1024m", and it's about 10 times slower. Don't notice any slowdown with 'memusage'.